# Why is typescript version not same as globally installed version on Windows 10?

Tags: typescript

I have installed Typescript globally using command line on my Windows 10 64-bit laptop. It says `typescript@3.6.3` after installing Typescript, yet when I run the command `tsc --version` it says version 1.0.3.0. These commands that I ran are as in screenshot below.

**Question**

Why is Typescript version not saying 3.6.3 when I run the command `tsc --version`?

When I run `where tsc` I get the following output.

[image: Typescript where output]

[image: Typescript version mismatch]

Comment: Could run `where tsc` and post the output?

Comment: @Vinz243, just added it to my question.

Comment: There you have your answer. The tsc inside Microsoft SDKs is taking precedence over npm's. You could remove the parent folder from your PATH variable

Comment: @Vinz243, you mean the environment variables in Windows 10?

Comment: exactly. It's either in your user variable or system variable

Comment: @Vinz243, I found the old typescript version path in System Environment variable PATH, but when I removed the entry `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\` I still get version as 1.0.3.0 when I rub tsc --version. Probably, I need to uninstall that old version of typescript?

Comment: Did you restart you PC?

Comment: No, I ran the command in same command window.

Comment: That's normal then the path doesn't update for existing proesses and command prompt

Comment: I uninstalled  `TypeScript Tools for Visual Studio 2015`  that was there when I went to Control Panel > Programs and Features.  Then, I opened a new command prompt and it gave 3.6.3 as tsc  version. I didn't restart my PC.

Comment: Yes because now the file is not found even though the folder is in the path for the active shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `where tsc` in command line gives you ordered list of global paths where `tsc.exe` was found.

In your case, you need to uninstall old version of TypeScript from:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Typescript\1.0\`

or, to remove this specific path from your environment variables `Path` variable.

However, more common use case is that your project (in this case `angular-hello-world`) build script **uses locally installed TypeScript version**, usually listed in `devDependencies` of your `package.json` and located in `node_modules` folder.

For example

```
{
    // ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^3.6.3",
        // ...
    }
}
```

To use project's **local version of TypeScript** you can use NodeJS command `npx`:

`npx tsc --version`

This will run local version of TypeScript and display it's version number.

Comment: Ok. I'll try and let you know. I have TypeScript Tools for Visual Studio 2015 installed when I go to Control Panel > Programs and Features.  Perhaps uninstalling that might work.

Comment: Uninstalling TypeScript Tools for Visual Studio 2015 did the trick. Did't need to restart my PC. Just closed previous command window and opened a new one. The version given by tsc --version command is now 3.6.3.